# error list index out of range instead of proper listing in python

Tags: python, file, keras

Following code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import skipgrams
from keras.preprocessing import text

with open('engl_bible.txt', 'r') as file:
norm_bible = file

tokenizer = text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(norm_bible)

word2id = tokenizer.word_counts
id2word = {v:k for k, v in word2id.items()}

vocab_size = len(word2id) + 1
embed_size = 100

wids = [[word2id[w] for w in text.text_to_word_sequence(doc)] for doc in norm_bible]

#print('Vocabulary Size:', vocab_size)
#print('Vocabulary Sample:', list(word2id.items())[:10])



# generate skip-grams
#skip_grams = keras.preprocessing.sequence.skipgrams(sequence, vocabulary_size, window_size=4, negative_samples=1.0, shuffle=True,
                                      # categorical=False, sampling_table=None, seed=None)

skip_grams = [skipgrams(wid, vocabulary_size=vocab_size, window_size=10) for wid in wids]

# view sample skip-grams
pairs = skip_grams[0]
labels = skip_grams[1]
for i in range(10):
    print("({:s} ({:d}), {:s} ({:d})) -> {:d}".format(id2word[pairs[i][0]], pairs[i][0],id2word[pairs[i][1]], pairs[i][1],labels[i]))
```

this should lead to an output like this:

```
(james (1154), king (13)) -> 1
(king (13), james (1154)) -> 1
(james (1154), perform (1249)) -> 0
(bible (5766), dismissed (6274)) -> 0
```

but the output I get is the following:

```
pairs = skip_grams[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: which means that skip_grams is empty... what did you do to debug the error?

Answer (score 0):

It means that `skip_grams` is holding an empty list. That's why when you are doing `skip_grams[0]`, you are getting the error as "IndexError: list index out of range" because there is nothing at 0th index in your list.

On seeing you code, I see these relevant lines:

```
with open('engl_bible.txt', 'r') as file:
    norm_bible = file
...

wids = [[word2id[w] for w in text.text_to_word_sequence(doc)] for doc in norm_bible]

...

skip_grams = [skipgrams(wid, vocabulary_size=vocab_size, window_size=10) for wid in wids]
```

which makes me think that your file 'engl_bible.txt' is empty.

**Empty file `'engl_bible.txt'`-> empty list `wids` -> empty list `skip_grams`**

Comment: thanks for your help. engl_bible.txt is not empty, if I do print(wids), I get a list  of integers (or a sequence of word indexes) with 
    [[], [], [3914], [8118], [7195], [1944], ...] 
but in the variable skip_gram the function skipgrams() cannot transform this sequence of word indexes (list of integers) into tuples of words of the form:
- (word, word in the same window), with label 1 (positive samples).
- (word, random word from the vocabulary), with label 0 (negative samples)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect you are not opening the file right and you might want to fix your indentations. Try opening the file with:

```
with open('engl_bible.txt', 'r') as file:
    norm_bible = file.read()
    #norm_bible = file.readlines()

print(len(norm_bible))
```

Your initial code does not actually read the file. `read()` returns the file contents as a string and `read_lines()` returns each newline as an element in a list. Seeing that you are applying a tokenizer, `read()` might be the way to go.

Then check if your `norm_bible` variable is not empty.